# Why isn't $+∞$ always included in the range of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I haven't paid much attention to it until now, but suddenly I had a question.

I have been studying functions and I noticed that the range of a function is often not defined to include positive infinity $\{+∞\}$.

Can anyone explain why positive infinity is not always included in the range of a function?

Comment: What would $\sin(x)$ be in such a case?  In any case $+\infty$ is not a real number, so is not in the domain for a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

Comment: Differentiation kind of doesn't work for functions with codomain $[-\infty,\infty]$ (if they actually have $f(x)=\infty$ somewhere). You would need some heavy workaround to even have a reasonable formulation (say, like in manifolds with boundary), but then there isn't a clear generalization to several variables.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I see now that including +∞ in the codomain could make formalizations quite complicated. Thank you for explaining this to me.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio One could take some projective space as the codomain. Those are nice manifolds (without boundary), and we can define differentiation on them without issue. Though we do need the context of differential geometry.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I know, but we were asked for $+\infty$, which to me suggests that there's some interest in the order relation. Which I don't think makes sense in $\Bbb P^1$.

Comment: If $+\infty$ (whatever it is) would be in the range of the function $f$, then this would mean that it exists $x$ such that $f(x)=+\infty$. This certainly won't be the case for any function $f:U\to\mathbb R$ (with, say, $U\subseteq\mathbb R$) simply because all values from the domain are mapped into _finite_ real numbers. What example do you have on your mind where it _would_ (?) make sense to include $+\infty$ in the range?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: sometimes it is useful to consider functions that can take the value $∞$, but this can cause some minor technical headaches, so there is a tradeoff.

For example, in measure theory, $ +∞$ (and possibly also $-∞$) are often included in the range of a function, since many of the results there hold for such functions.

In this case, it is necessary to establish some conventions for calculating with infinity, e.g. for $x∈ ℝ$, $x+∞ :=∞$. It is also useful to define $0·∞ = 0$, but the trouble with this is that this 'extended' multiplication is not continuous anymore. Another issue: the difference of two functions that can take the value $∞$ is possibly ill-defined, since there is no particularly sensible way to give meaning to "$∞-∞$". For measure theory, it is usually considered 'worth it' to deal with these. On the other hand, in calculus, it seems to create more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Thank you! @jro How about in algebra?

Comment: @Coco, I am not aware, sorry.